# Angular5 and ngx-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm with the problem using Typeahead of ngx-bootstrap after build of my project:

```
index.js:... Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TypeaheadDirective -> ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TypeaheadDirective -> ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!
```

The versions in my package.json are as follows:

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
"typescript": "^2.4.2",
```

In my app.component it is imported as follows:

```
import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        TypeaheadModule.forRoot(),
    ],
....
```

Comment: Is that lazy loading module?

Comment: yes, is lazy loading module

Comment: Try to add `TypeaheadModule.forRoot()` into the root module, and remove it from here